# change bash_profile not working

Tags: composer-php, bash, mamp-pro

I am working on Mac El Capitan.  I have MAMP Pro installed.  I am attempting to install composer.  Part of the process is making it accessible globally.  I have gone in and done vim ~/.bash_profile and added: export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/bin:$PATH

I am using PHP 7.0.0.  However when I save and exit (escape :wq) and then run which PHP it is still pointing to the original folder.  I have exited out of the terminal window and come back in.  I have also run source ~/.bash_profile.  Still the which php version points to /usr/bin/php

Any suggestions for what to try next?

Comment: I have now also tried alias php=/Application/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/bin/php;  This is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me except I ended up putting composer in an apps folder rather than in my usr/bin.

telliott.io/node/969

Comment: As a side note, I also didn't capitalize the entire PATH despite what I had listed here.